# Linux invoke key combination by CLI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, keyboard

Is there a way of invoking a key combination over the CLI?

I mean something like:

`$ invoke ALT+4`

Comment: Can you provide some context for why you would want to do this?  Are you connected to the physical console, in an X11 session, connected via ssh/other?

Comment: X11, ubuntu oneiric desktop edition. I just need to invoke those keys after X minutes, for example `CTRL+ALT+L` to Lock Screen after X minutes

Comment: Why wouldn't you use one of the many screen saver programs for that purpose?

Comment: that was an example, I do want to know how invoke key combinations :)

Comment: Ok, but to be clear, you are primarily concerned with how to do this under X11?  Since the methods for a remote terminal, console, and X11 will each be different.

Comment: yes, my objection is for X11 but if there is a solution for a console environment or remote terminal... glad to learn it to :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cloest I can find in some quick Google searches might be something like [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/).

> What is xdotool? This tool lets you simulate keyboard input and mouse
>   activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using X11's XTEST
>   extension and other Xlib functions.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try virtual keyboard [xvkbd](http://michkhoo.blogspot.com/2009/08/xvkbd-quick-reference.html).